# MVC 4 Multiple applications with common login

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have created multiple web applications with a common login.  I have a separate membership database.  User going to http://localhost will be automatically redirected to http://localhost/home.  Here user must login.  Once they're login, there will be links to applications that they have access to.  But the problem is when they click on one of the links (eg: http://localhost/webapp1), they are redirected to the login screen of that application instead of directly to the index page of that application.  How do I let the application know that user has been authenticated?

Answer (score 0):

When a user is authenticated, a cookie is added. It is this cookie that determines whether a user is "logged in" or not. Importantly, this cookie is encrypted and tied to a particular domain. That means two things for you:

1. This will only ever work if all the sites are on the same domain. They can be on *subdomains*, but they all must be off the same root domain (i.e. site1.foo.com and site2.foo.com would be fine, but site1.com and site2.com would not work).
2. All of the sites much be able to decrypt the same cookie, which means they all must share the same machine key. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755177(v=ws.10).aspx for additional information.

Since everything is currently running off localhost, #2 is likely your issue. However, keep #1 in mind when deploying.